# How to sort a list of lists in lexicographic order?

Tags: sorting, haskell, lexicographic

I want to sort the elements of a Haskell list in lexicographic order, Is there any method?

Before sorted:

```
[ [], [1,2], [1], [1,2,3], [2], [1,3], [2,3], [3]]
```

After sorted:

```
[ [], [1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [1,3], [2], [2,3], [3]]
```

Comment: Have you tried just using `sort`?!

Comment: I hate to sound rude, but did it not occur to just search for something like "Haskell sort list"?

Comment: Most straightforward approach: just define function 
lex_compare :: String -> String -> Ordering 
which compares two lists according desired order then use sortBy function.

Comment: @user2894391: Somebody has thought ahead: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.4.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Classes.html#line-189

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes, you're right. But maybe OP wanted some explanation of how does this work?

Comment: @user2894391: Maybe... The question is not really good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [default `Ord`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.4.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Classes.html#line-189) instance for lists actually works that way:

```
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> sort [ [], [1,2], [1], [1,2,3], [2], [1,3], [2,3], [3]]
[[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,3],[2],[2,3],[3]]
```